# Calculate frequency and percentage within a subgroup in R

Tags: percentage, frequency-distribution

I have a data frame called measlescases comprised of columns like "Final Classification' 'ProvinceofResidence', 'AgeCategory', 'Vaccinationstatus', etc.

I would like to calculate the number of measles cases (obtained from the 'Final Classification' column) each by 'ProvinceofResidence', 'AgeCategory', 'Vaccinationstatus'.

Can someone give me a line of code using one of these columns as examples?

Thanks

YEt to try. Still new to R